Prove that a subspace G of $X \oplus Y$ is the graph of a linear map if and only if $X \oplus Y = G \oplus Y$.
I'm working on the following problem from a master's course in advanced vector spaces:

The graph of a map $A : X \rightarrow Y$ is defined as the set of all pairs $(x,A x)$ in $X \times Y$.  Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are vector spaces,

prove that $A$ is linear if and only if its graph is a subspace of $X \oplus Y$, and
prove that a subspace $G \subseteq X \oplus Y$ is the graph of a linear map if and only if $X \oplus Y = G \oplus Y$. Regard $Y$ as a subspace of $X \oplus Y$ so that $G \oplus Y$ is an internal direct sum between two subspaces of the vector space $V = X \oplus Y$.


I have proved the first part, but I'm struggling with even understanding the second part of the question. It seems that I have to prove ("=>") that the graph of a linear map equals the entire vector space, and ("<=") that a graph's map is linear if it maps to the entire vector space, but I'm not sure.
Any help is much appreciated :)

I believe it’s instructive to produce the linear transformation explicitly.
If $G$ is complement to $Y$ in $X \oplus Y$, then the composition $$G \to X \oplus Y \to X$$ of the inclusion followed by the projection is an isomorphism. Indeed, since $G$ is a complement to $Y$, it intersects the kernel at the zero vector. It’s also surjective since the projection is.
Let’s call the above linear isomorphism $T$. Then $G$ is a graph for the linear transformation given by the inverse of $T$ followed by projection onto $Y$.
For the other direction, any graph is a complement since the projection $G \to X$ is easily seen to be an isomorphism.

Let $G$ be a subspace of $X\oplus Y$.

$G$ is the graph of a map $A:X\to Y$ (which is then automatically linear by the first question) iff
$$\forall x\in X\quad\exists!y\in Y\quad(x,y)\in G.\tag1\label{eq1}$$
$G$ is a complement of $Y$ in $X\oplus Y$ iff $\forall(u,v)\in X\oplus Y\quad\exists!((x,y),z)\in G\times Y\quad u=x,v=y+z$, i.e. iff
$$\forall(u,v)\in X\oplus Y\quad\exists!z\in Y\quad (u,v-z)\in G.\tag2\label{eq2}$$

\eqref{eq1}$\implies$\eqref{eq2}: Given $(u,v)\in X\oplus Y$, if $G$ is the graph of $A$ then $(u,v-z)\in G\iff v-z=A(u)\iff z=v-A(u)$.
\eqref{eq2}$\implies$\eqref{eq1}: Applying \eqref{eq2} to $(u,v)=(x,0)$  proves $\forall x\in X\quad\exists!z\in Y\quad (x,-z)\in G$, which is equivalent to \eqref{eq1}.
